# How can you use multiple input streams for input parameters?

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing

I want to run a command line script that requires several parameters.  Specifically:

> perl prinseq-lite.pl -fastq file1.fq.gz -fastq2 file2.fq.gz
>
> \ -out_good goodfile.out -out_bad badfile.out -log prin.log
>
> \ -ns_max_n 5 ... more_params ...

The problem is that the files are zipped, and must be processed without first unzipping and storing them, because the unzipped file sizes are very large and this command will be run on a large number of files.

So what I need to do is to unzip the input on the fly.  Previously, user l0b0, suggested that multiple input streams might be a solution.  I have tried the following, but seem to be passing an empty input stream here as the program claims the input files are empty.

> perl prinseq-lite.pl -fastq <(zcat f1.gz) -fastq2 <(zcat f2.gz) ...
>
> perl prinseq-lite.pl -fastq 1< <(zcat f1.gz) -fastq2 2< <(zcat f2.gz) ...

So what I need to do, in short, is provide unzipped input for multiple parameters to this program.

Can someone tell me the proper way to do this, and/or what I'm doing wrong with my current attempts?  Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Doubtful that they're *empty*. What they will be, however, is *non-seekable*; if your `prinseq-lite.pl` needs to be able to seek inside the file or read it more than once, *that* will be a problem.

Comment: ...which is to say that we actually need to more about the contents of your specific Perl script to answer this question well.

Comment: (similarly, if your program is trying to read the input file's length to provide status info, *that'll* fail too; I could see something sloppily written treating that the same as being empty).

Comment: The program manual is here: http://prinseq.sourceforge.net/manual.html .  It's a piece of scientific software and not just some script I wrote.  It's capable of handling the two input version, but it doesn't handle zipped files.  As far as I can tell no one has a good workaround for this yet, but I can see whatever solution we find here being used by others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the easiest might be to make named pipes for the output of `gzunip`, then use those names pipes in the command:

```
mkfifo file1.fq file2.fq file3.fq ...
gunzip -c file1.fq.gz > file1.fq &
gunzip -c file2.fq.gz > file2.fq &
gunzip -c file3.fq.gz > file3.fq &
```

Then call your program with those pipes as file names:

```
perl prinseq-lite.pl -fastq file1.fq -fastq2 file2.fq -fastq3 file3.fq ...
```

Comment: If `<(...)` doesn't work, I'd be surprised if named pipes would work either. On many platforms, a process substitution *is replaced with* a named pipe by the shell; in others, it'll be something like `/dev/fd/10` pointing to an anonymous pipe -- but most of the restrictions that would make a program fail with a `/dev/fd` pointer to an anonymous pipe will make it fail with a named pipe too.

Comment: Wouldn't using named pipes essentially unzip the files to the filesystem exactly the same as if I unzipped them and provided the unzipped files to the program?

Comment: No, @AdamPrice, it doesn't actually write to the filesystem.  It's all in memory.

Comment: I've been trying the named pipe approach, so far it just hangs with no output or logs.  I think I might need to find a different approach for this particular program.  Have had fun learning about named pipes though!